# Send message to a non-friend facebook user?

Tags: facebook

I am developing a Facebook application. It must notify random people on Facebook about a certain event that happens related to them. I mean random people - not just those who installed the app, that's a key point.

Yeah I know it sounds like a spammy annoying application, but I swear, it's not that kind that everyone hates. :)

Is there a way to send anything (wall post? message?) to a user that did not previously installed the app?

Comment: Oh, so then it's a spammy annoying application of the type everyone loves? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible as per [facebook's privacy policy](http://www.facebook.com/policy.php). There should be some sort of connection like friendship/application user to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but only if you direct the acting user to the send message URL in a new window. If you are talking about an automated way, it is not technically possible at the moment.

Comment: "Automated way": do you mean spam?

Comment: No, I mean, there was no API available for it at the time, but my answer is a year old, which is decades in Facebook time. There may very well now be an actual API for this, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible through request dialog api: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/