# Implementing Chat On Facebook Web App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, chat, facebook-chat

This is a not exactly a technical question - sorry in advance .

I have a social web app on Facebook and I want to give my app's users the ability to chat between themselves (exactly the way facebook chat looks). As I see it here are my options :

1 : Regarding the Facebook Chat API  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/  it is not clear to me whether this works only for a user's Facebook friends or will I have the ability to let non friends chat too (it is very important since 99% of my users aren't supposed to be Facebook friends). I read it a few times and it seems that this service is only for a Facebook user and his Facebook friends , but maybe I am wrong ?

2 : If I am right and Facebook Chat API is only for friends , what is an easy and safe way to implement a simple chat between 2 users myself? (I am not expecting millions of users on my app so it's not out of the question for my app to implement a chat).

Answer (score 0):

Per [Send message to a non-friend facebook user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211962/send-message-to-a-non-friend-facebook-user), you cannot send chat messages via the API between Facebook users that are not connected.

Comment: Ok thank you - you are saying the Facebook API is only for a user's Facebook friends . Do you have any ideas\suggestions on implementing chat for my app's users who aren't necessarily friends of one another?